# In need of a JS date library. DateJS hasn't been updated since around 2007-2008. Red flag?

Tags: javascript, datejs

I'm building a calendar-based web app, and am in great need of a javascript Date library-- something similar to python's [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).  I came across [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/). The functionality looks great.  My only hesitance is that the repo hasn't been touched since early 2008.  Usually this is a (very) bad sign for an open source project. So I wanted to check whether people currently use, trust and recommend this library, or whether its just an abandoned set of good intentions with good SEO.  If not, is there another comprehensive JS date library I should be looking at?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd like to recommend [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) - a very lightweight, yet surprisingly capable Date JS library. )

Comment: Moment.js is great for formatting and manipulating dates, but parsing natural-language dates is where DateJS really shines, and is something moment.js does not support.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to replace this, which as I understand, momentjs cannot do-> Date.next().jul().first().sun()

Answer (score 7):

Try https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs ,

It is a forked version of http://www.datejs.com/

It is actively maintained by new Author !

Answer (score 2):

DateJS works wonders for us.  I am not really concerned that development seems to have stalled as it is pretty complete as-is.